Unable to connect RDS Database with MySQL workbench even with Public Access
I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot + MySQL application on AWS.
My deployment is as follows-

Default VPC
3 public subnets
AWS Elastic Beanstalk, deployed in one AZ.
MySQL database (using RDS) is in same AZ and allows public access.

The security group for both, Beanstalk and RDS instance is same and have public access inbound rules (all-traffic-0.0.0.0/0-all ports allowed).

The ACL also allows internet connectivity with inbound and outbound rules.

The route table has necessary routes to allow internet access.


When trying to connect my database with MySQL workbench using the endpoint, my username and password, I get the following error-

I have ensured that the security group and ACL allow access and the route table has route for inbound and outbound traffic. Still it is not able to connect.
I referred the following video on VPC-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2JOHLHh4rI&t=4099s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org
I am not able to understand, what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Side-note: It is typically better to use separate Security Groups for the database and app server. The Security Group on the app server (App-SG) should permit Inbound access on ports 80 and 443 and Outbound access to All. The Database Security Group (DB-SG) should permit Inbound access from your personal IP address and from App-SG. That is, DB-SG should specifically reference App-SG, which will allow any EC2 instance associated with App-SG to access the database.

@JohnRotenstein thanks for your suggestion and advise. I will try to do it as well, once I am able to resolve this issue. Being a backend dev, I am quite new to cloud and would adopt the best practices.

Your configuration is correct.
When I attempt to connect to it, I get the message:

Access denied for user 'foo'@'101.113.128.31' (using password: YES)

This means that I could successfully communicate with your database, but was denied access due to incorrect login details. If you are receiving a different response, then it might be due to your computer or your network.
If you are going to provision the database in a public subnet, I recommend that you limit access by restricting the range of IP addresses that can connect to the database. You should only allow access from your own IP address and the the CIDR range of the VPC (172.31.0.0/16).

I have tried to connect from my local computer but getting the message as seen in the image above. I have tried using a VPN to connect, but still getting the same error- "Failed to connect to MySQL at  ...." "Lost connection to MySQL server at...".

As far as the public access is concerned, unfortunately I am using a restricted network and have to switch between networks very often and sometimes use VPN. That's why I can't provide a pre-determined IP address to allow limited access.

Your connectivity problem is likely caused by your local network. Any possibility of tethering to your phone to test it with a different network? Also, when you say that you tried using a VPN, how did that VPN connect to the database's network?

The Ethernet I use restricts certain URLs (like RDS endpoints, beanstalk URLs) and doesn't allow to directly connect. So, I use a VPN (like Proton) to access the AWS servers from my laptop. As far as phone is concerned I have checked with it but was not able to connect. Will check again once again.
Thank You.
